# React DnD change div style only when dragging

Tags: react-dnd

I am implementing the drag and drop mechanic using `react-dnd` library, but I find it hard to style my drop targets. I want to show the user which drop target is available to drop on, but using the `isOver` and `canDrop` will only style the item that is currently being hovered on.
If I use the `!isOver` value, all the divs are being styled, without even dragging any of the elements.
How can I style the drop targets **only** when the dragging of an element happens?
This is my code so far, for a `@DropTarget`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {DropTarget} from 'react-dnd';
import {ItemTypes} from './Constants';

const target = {
    drop(props, monitor, component){
        // console.log("Dropped on", props.id);
    },

    canDrop(props, monitor, component){
        var cardColumn = monitor.getItem().column;
        var targetColumn = props.column;
        return false; // still testing styling when only an element is being dragged on the page
    }

};

@DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, target, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
    isOver: monitor.isOver({shallow: true}),
    canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
}))
class CardList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.addClass = this.addClass.bind(this);
    }

    addClass(){
        const {isOver, canDrop} = this.props;
        if(isOver && canDrop){
            return "willDrop"; // green background for .card-list
        }
        if(isOver && !canDrop){
            return "noDrop"; // red background for .card-list
        }
        if(!isOver && !canDrop){
            return ""; // will style all the backgrounds in a color, but not when dragging
        }

    }

    render(){
        const {connectDropTarget} = this.props;

        return connectDropTarget(
            <div class={"card-list col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 " + this.addClass()} id={this.props.id}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CardList;
```

Is there a way to get the `isDragging` value when an element is being dragged on the page, since this is the only possibility to obtain what I want.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both isOver and canDrop implicitly do the isDragging check, per http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target-monitor.html - note that they only return true if a drag operation is in progress. Therefore, if you want to style drop targets such that only when something that can be dragged is being dragged, then I think you need another case in your addClass() function to handle that, like this:

```
addClass(){
    const {isOver, canDrop} = this.props;
    if(isOver && canDrop){
        return "willDrop"; // green background for .card-list
    }
    if(isOver && !canDrop){
        return "noDrop"; // red background for .card-list
    }
    if(!isOver && canDrop){
        return ""; // THIS BLOCK WILL EXECUTE IF SOMETHING IS BEING DRAGGED THAT *COULD* BE DROPPED HERE
    }
}
```

And I don't think you want the !isOver && !canDrop block - this will execute even when nothing is being dragged at all.